# Two conjectural series for $\pi$ involving the central trinomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

For each $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, the central trinomial coefficient $T_n$ is defined as the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(x^2+x+1)^n$. It is easy to see that $T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}k$.

On December 7, 2019, I conjectured that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(105k-44)T_{k-1}}{k^2\binom{2k}k^23^{k-1}}=\frac{5\pi}{\sqrt3}+6\log3\tag{1}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(5k-2)T_{k-1}}{k^2\binom{2k}k^2(k-1)3^{k-1}}=\frac{21-2\sqrt3\,\pi-9\log3}{12}.\tag{2}$$
As the two series converge very fast, it is easy to check (1) and (2) numerically. The two identities and related congruences appear in Section 10 of my recent preprint [*New series for powers of $\pi$ and related congruences*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05456). I'm unable to find proofs of $(1)$ and $(2)$. So, here I ask the following question.

**Question.** How to prove the conjectural identities $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: How did you find these identities?

Comment: The forms of the right-hand sides suggest looking at $\sum_{k = 2}^\infty T_{k - 1} \frac{105k^2 - 109k + 28}{k^2 {{2k}\choose{k}}^2 (k - 1) 3^{k - 1}}$ and $\sum_{k = 2}^\infty T_{k - 1} \frac{105k^2 - 99k + 24}{k^2 {{2k}\choose{k}}^2 (k - 1) 3^{k - 1}}$; have you looked at them?

Comment: @user44191 Note that  $105k^2-99k+24=(105k-44)(k-1)+10(5k-2)$. So $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(105k^2-99k+24)T_{k-1}}{k^2\binom{2k}k^2(k-1)3^{k-1}}=\frac{9-6\log3}{4}.$$

Comment: That's exactly why I chose those - they separate out the $\log 3$ and $\pi \sqrt{3}$ terms, if I haven't made an arithmetic mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but a reduction to a definite integral.

First, Lagrange inversion implies that the generating function for $T_k$ is $${\cal T}(z):=(1-2z-3z^2)^{-\frac12}=((1+z)(1-3z))^{-\frac12},$$ 
and thus $T_k = [z^k]\ {\cal T}(z)$. Notice that
$${\cal T}'(z) = \frac{1+3z}{(1+z)(1-3z)}{\cal T}(z).$$

Second, by the property of the beta function, we have
$$\frac{1}{k\binom{2k}k} = B(k+1,k) = \int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{k-1}\,{\rm d}x = \frac12 \int_0^1 x^{k-1}(1-x)^{k-1}\,{\rm d}x.$$

It follows that 
$$I_1:=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{T_{k-1}}{k^2\binom{2k}k^2 3^{k-1}} =
\frac14 \int_0^1\int_0^1 {\cal T}\big( \frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)}{3} \big)\,{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$$
and
$$I_2 := \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(k-1) T_{k-1}}{k^2\binom{2k}k^2 3^{k-1}} =
\frac14 \int_0^1\int_0^1\, \frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)}3\, {\cal T}'\big( \frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)}{3} \big)\,{\rm d}x{\rm d}y.$$

Since $105k-44 = 105(k-1)+61$, the first sum in question equals $105 I_2 + 61 I_1$.

The second sum in question can be reduced to a definite integral similarly.