# Length of isoline $x(1-x)y(1-y)=c$

Tags: integration, algebraic-curves, plane-geometry

For the integral appearing in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353573), it may be beneficial to derive the length $L(c)$ of the isoline:
$$x(1-x)y(1-y) = c,$$
where $x,y$ are ranging in $[0,1]$, and constant $c\in [0,\frac1{16}]$.

It is clear that $L(0)=4$ and $L(\frac{1}{16})=0$. Here is a plot of these isolines for some $c$:

[image: Isolines x(1-x)y(1-y)=c]

Straightforward derivation leads to an integral like
$$L(c) = 4 \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-16c}}2}^{\frac12}\,\, \sqrt{1 - \frac{c^2 (1-2x)^2}{(4c - x+x^2)(1-x)^3 x^3} }\,\, {\rm d}x$$

> Q: Is there a simple expression for $L(c)$?

Comment: In your integral $L(0)=2$, not $4$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: Not quite. The denominator has a factor $4c-x+x^2$ that is zero for $c=0$ and $x=0$. So, $L(0)$ must be computed as $\lim_{c\to 0^+} L(c)$.

Comment: the integral is complex for small $c$...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: What do you mean?

Comment: for $c=1/100$ it evaluates to $1.475(1+i)$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: For $c=1/100$, Maple computes L(c) as a real number 3.211769473. How did you compute it?

Comment: NIntegrate[4*Sqrt[1+c^2*(1-2*x)^2/((4*c-x+x^2)*(1-x)^3*x^3)],{x,1/2-Sqrt[1-16*c]/2,1/2}]

Comment: at $c=1/100$, the argument of the square root becomes negative for $x<0.1127$; it's a simple test to see that at $c=1/100$, $x=1/10$ the argument of the square root is –551/729.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I found the issue - it was wrong sign in the integral expression (and correct one in my Maple expression). Now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This can be also parameterized as $$(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4t},1\pm\sqrt{1-4c/t})$$ for $4c\le t \le 1/4$, which leads to an arclength formula of $$8\int_{4c}^{1/4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-4t)^3}-\frac{c^2(3c-t)^2}{(4c-t)^3t^5}}\,dt$$

Comment: @MattF.: I've got slightly simpler expression: $$4\int_{4c}^{\frac14} \sqrt{  \frac{1}{1-4t} + \frac{c^2}{(t-4c)t^3} }\,{\rm d}t.$$

Comment: @MattF.: It comes from the parametrization that you suggested. The expression under the square root is $\left(\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2$.

Comment: You are correct, I was accidentally squaring second derivatives.